# Android lock screen show again after it has been disabled (using lock.disableKeyguard())

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, lockscreen, wakelock

Hey Im writing a launcher, in which Im building my own custom lockscreen.

the custom lockscreen is an activity which being launched whenever 
the screen is off (by listening to Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)

to disable android's lockscreen I use this code:

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

It all works good, till some point, in which android's lockscreen is 
turned on again (like it has never beem disabled before).

It happens a lot on samsung galaxy 2 (but happens also on other phones).

What Im I doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it somehow by calling

```
 KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
 KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
 lock.disableKeyguard();
```

right before I start the lock screen activity

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled DevicePolicyMangnager? if not that function won't work.

this comes from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html):

> Note: This call has no effect while any DevicePolicyManager is enabled
>   that requires a password.

[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) is a tutorial about it. Anyway i think it's not what you are looking for cause anytime your app will do that the user will have to give a password to give you admin permissions.

in general there are no way to programmatically disable the KeyGuard ( if secure pin, password, pattern, face ) and the most you can do is to show an activity on top of it.